# Ajax após página completamente carregada

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um código bem lento rodando no lado servidor, para evitar o atraso na renderização na página, resolvi chamar a função via `ajax` após a página carregada, utilizei das duas formas mas ambas não funcionaram:

Com o `$(document).ready` a página é exibida, mas arquivos de fontes (Google Fonts) e ícones são carregado após.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ ... });
});
```

Já com o `$(window).bind` a página é inteiramente exibida após concluir a função.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $.ajax({ ... });
});
```

Comment: Voce quer chamar um ajax depois que as fontes forem carregadas eh isso?

Comment: Exatamente @leonardo

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [tópico](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936816/call-a-function-after-complete-page-load)
Parece que a solução não funciona bem em todos os browsers, por isso o recomendado foi que usasse `setTimeout` para conseguir o resultado desejado.

Comment: Podes colocar o código que tens agora para carregar as fontes? Se estiverem dentro da `<head>` carregam antes do `domready` ou  `load`

Comment: Está a usar o `$(window).bind("load", ...` no topo da página? Penso que tem de estar para funcionar corretamente.

Comment: Não entendi bem o problema. A variação com `bind` dá o resultado que você quer?

Comment: Coloca o ajax no final da pagina

Answer (score 1):

O método ready é executado uma vez que o DOM está concluído, isso não significa que sua página está totalmente renderizada.

Tente utilizar o seguinte código:

```
window.onload = function() { <seucódigoaqui> };
```